# Is llama meat popular amongst Britain's gurkha communities?

Tags: nutrition, united-kingdom

In "[Eating this exotic meat may seriously damage your health](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/home-news/eating-this-exotic-meat-may-seriously-damage-your-health-8660895.html)" (2013-06-16) *The Independent* claims:

> Although still relatively rare, llama is increasingly popular, especially among Britain’s gurkha communities, which regard it as a premium meat.

I can't find any evidence that llama meat is consumed (in disproportionate amounts, as implied by the quote) by Britain's gurkha community, let alone that it is "popular." Is this claim true?

Comment: Looking through the article I couldn't find any claim that llama meat is hazardous, other than the understandable hazard that it may come from questionable sources.

Comment: @DanielRHicks: While that may be true, that's irrelevant to what the OP was asking about.

Comment: It is at least probable, given the laws of supply and demand - and seeing that [there is supply](https://www.keziefoods.co.uk/Catalogue/Lean-Meats/Exotic-Meats/Llama-Meat) ...

Comment: @DanielRHicks I added "in disproportionate amounts", as the quote implies. I agree it's likely that at least one person who identifies as gurkha has consumed llama meat…